# CALayer Matrix Layout

Tags: ios, layout, calayer

Hello StackOverflow,

I am trying to draw a grid *(think: sudoku, e.g. lines and contents)* in `CALayer`.

Having never used `CALayer` before, what are the starting points, and best practices for doing so? Does anyone have something similar, or even code that I could take a peek at?

Many thanks,

Alexandre.

Comment: Are you looking for a tutorial?

Comment: @UsamaArshad : If you know of one, I would be grateful. However, any pointers and information would be appreciated !

Comment: [This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/calayers-tutorial-for-ios-introduction-to-calayers-tutorial) is a good tutorial for starters. [The Class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/) can always be of great help too.

Comment: [Tutorial for swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90488/calayer-in-ios-with-swift-10-examples).